# Differenciate Between User Requests and AJAX/Resource Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers

I'm attempting to create an app with Node.js (using `http.createServer()`) which will be a single page application with requests for data via XMLHttpRequest. To do this I need to be able to differentiate between a user navigating to my domain, and AJAX requests and requests generated by the browser for linked resources.

If the request is from the user I always want to return the `index.html` page which will handle requesting content but if the request is browser generated or AJAX and is for CSS, Javascript or other linked files I want to serve those files. Is there any way to detect this?

Looking at the request headers for the different file types I saw the `referer` header appeared when the request for content was generated by the page. I figured that was the solution I was looking for but that header is also set when a user clicks on a link to the page making it useless.

The only other thing which seems to change is the `accept` header which could sort of work but might not be a catch all solution. Any user requests always seem to have `text/html` as the preferred return type regardless of which url was entered. I could detect that but I'm pretty sure AJAX requests for html files would also have that `accept` header which would cause problems.

Is there anything I'm missing here (any headers or properties I can look for)?

---

**Edit:** I do not need the solution to protect files and I don't care about users bypassing it with their own requests. My intention is not to hide files or make them secure, but rather to keep any data that is requested within the scope of the app.

For example, if a user navigates to `http://example.com/images/someimage.jpg` they are instead shown the `index.html` file which can then show the image in a richer context and include all of the links and functionality to go with it.

**TL/DR:** I need to detect when someone is trying to access the app to then serve them the index page and have that send them the content they want. I also need to detect when the browser has requested resources (JS, CSS, HTML, images, etc) needed by the app to be able to actually return the resource not the index file.

Comment: If this is to stop leeches from grabbing data, you are up against how important your data is. If not, can the user accidentally find and send other requests than the index.html?

Comment: how what you want to do is different from what express does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not technically an answer to the question but I found a simple solution which does what I want: prefix all app based requests with a subdomain eg. `http://data.example.com/`. It's then really simple to check the `host` header for that subdomain: if present send the resource else send the index page.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of HTTP protocol there are NO difference between a *user-generated-query* and a *browser-generated-query*.

Every query is just... a query.
You can make a query with a command line, with a browser, you can click a link, send some ascii text via telnet, request a proxy which will make the query for you, the server goal is never to identify how the query was requested by the user.

See for example a request made by a user on a reverse proxy cache, this query will never reach your server (response comes from the cache), the first query made to build this response could have been made by *a real user* or by a browser.

In terms of security trying to control that the user is never requesting data *by-himself* cannot be done by detecting that the query is a real human click (and search google for clickjacking if you want to be afraid). Every query that a browser can make can also be played by the user, every one, you have no way to prevent that.

Some browsers plugins are even doing pre-fetching, detecting links on the page and making the request before you do it yourself (if it's a GET query).

For ajax, some libraries like JQuery will add an `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header, and this is used on most framework to detect ajax mode.
But it is more robust to depend on a location policy for that (like making your ajax queries with a `/format/ajax`, which could also be used on other ways (like `/format/json`, `/format/html`, or `/format/csv`).

Spending time on a location policy based routing is certainly more usefull.

But one thing can make a difference, POST queries are not indempotent, it means the browser cannot make a POST query **without** a real user interaction, because a POST query may alter the state of the session or the state of the server data (but js can make POST queries, this is just a default behavior of browsers). The browser will never automatically retrieve a POST query, so you could make a website where all users interactions are POST queries (via forms or via some js altering link clicks to send POST ajax queries instead). But I'm not that's your real goal.